# How to solve Core Data error: Attempt to add read-only file at path when trying to access Core Data container in the app extension today widget?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios10

I am trying to access a database using Core Data inside a today extension widget.

The function that creates the Core Data container is this:

```
func createContainer(completion: @escaping (NSPersistentContainer) -> ()) {
    let applicationGroupIdentifier = "group.com.name.exampleApp.sharedContainer"

    guard let newURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: applicationGroupIdentifier)
        else { fatalError("Could not create persistent store URL") }

    let persistentStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription()

    persistentStoreDescription.url = newURL

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ContainerName")

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [persistentStoreDescription]

    container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
        guard error == nil else { fatalError("Failed to load store:\(String(describing: error))") }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(container) }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> CoreData: error: Attempt to add read-only file at path
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/C9324B65B-265C-4264-95DE-B5AC5C9DAFD0/
>   read/write. Adding it read-only instead. This will be a hard error in
>   the future; you must specify the NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption.

If I specify the NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption like this:

```
persistentStoreDescription.isReadOnly = false
```

I get the error:

> Failed to load store:Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513
>   "The file couldn’t be saved because you don’t have permission."):

What might be the cause and the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem and solved it by adding

```
let directory = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.identifier")!
let url = directory.appendingPathComponent("MyDatabaseName.sqlite")
```

CoreData probably tried to open the base folder as its sqlite database, which did not go so well.

Adding isReadOnly didn't allow CoreData to repurpose the Folder either :)

Source: https://github.com/maximbilan/iOS-Shared-CoreData-Storage-for-App-Groups

Comment: I am using the same source as you are but on a different extension (unwantedCommunicationExtension). I am still getting the same error when I'm trying to write from the extension itself

Comment: @tink So `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/C9324B65B-265C-4264-95DE-B5AC5C9DAFD0/`: is part of your error?

Comment: Turned out every extension has different set of privacy catch. The one I am using (Unwanted Comm. Reporting) doesn't allow to write anything from the extension part, not even NSUserDefaults .. I was trying many things and at some point I was getting the error you mentioned as well. I can't recall what I did to fix it.. Im sorry!

Comment: @tink Happens to me all the time. :) So you got it to write despite not able to, or did you just avoid that? That sounds like an interesting story.

Comment: It wasn't worth taking a shot at.. Even if I would bypass some how, they would just reject the app. So I changed my back-end completely. I wanted to store all reported messages in a core data and show it the app for report history, but now I am passing my UUID to the backend and make a call to retrieve it in app. Caveat: You have to open app first at least once, before anything else. (prolly make user accept terms while on the back store whatever you need in the user defaults)
bottom-line: You can pass whatever you want from your app to the extension but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

1. In extension's info.plist set: NSExtension --> NSExtensionAttributes --> RequestOpenAccess --> YES
2. In Settings on device set: Your app --> (Extension type - eg.: Keyboard) --> Allow Full Access